# How do you change the color of the QT line widget in QT Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

Kaveish offers a nice piece of code to work with on this 
[How does designer create a Line widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053839/how-does-designer-create-a-line-widget)
How would I change the color of those lines to blue from their black default color.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different approaches for this, depending on your need. I'm going to post examples in Python, but porting to C++ is simple enough.

## Set the QPalette

If you want to keep the look of the current style, you could try to set the palette colors. This works fine on Linux with the default Breeze and Oxygen styles:

```
palette = self.line.palette()
palette.setColor(palette.Window, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.lightGreen)
self.line.setPalette(palette)
```

Unfortunally not all theme/styles are implemented in the same way, and both the Windows and Fusion styles need to set the color for the `palette.Dark` role, which makes the whole solution very platform and style dependent, as an user could have his/her own styles installed.

## Stylesheet

The stylesheet solution requires to implement the `border` properties of the QFrame widget subclass, but doesn't look always very good and it's better to `setFixedHeight` (or width for vertical lines) to 2 pixel maximum.

```
self.line.setStyleSheet('''
    MyLineClass {
        border: 0.5px solid green;
        border-style: inset;
    }
''')
```

## QPaintEvent

Then there's the custom paint solution. This is a simple implementation that obtains an effect similar to the Oxygen "smooth" lines.

```
class MyHorizontalLine(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    grad = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0)
    grad.setCoordinateMode(self.grad.StretchToDeviceMode)
    grad.setCoordinateMode(self.grad.ObjectBoundingMode)
    grad.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.transparent))
    grad.setColorAt(.5, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkGray))
    grad.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.transparent))
    gradPen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QBrush(grad), 1)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.translate(.5, self.rect().center().y() - .5)
        qp.setPen(self.gradPen)
        qp.drawLine(0, 0, self.width(), 0)
        qp.translate(0, 1)
        qp.setOpacity(.5)
        qp.drawLine(0, 0, self.width(), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: Following @VaderB's comment, *color* attribute works:

```
QFrame *verticalLine = new QFrame(this);
verticalLine->setFrameShape(QFrame::VLine);
verticalLine->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(221, 221, 221)");
```

---

Putting StyleSheet works for me. For example, in Designer:

```
#line, #line_2 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

Here, `line and line_2` are lines (: And in widget class:

```
line->setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: #0000FF;"));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This will change the _background color_, not the _color_ of the line.

Comment: the code works, I tested. It changes **background color** of the **line** which is the **color** of the **line** :)

Comment: I tested this and it changed the color of the area containing the line instead of the line color.

Comment: @FedericoRubbi, It seems you are right. If you use it in a layout, it just gives an impression of changed line color. You can use in the same way. I will update my answer

Comment: Just use `color` attribute, like this:
`#line{color: white;}`